# Default filter in Django model

Tags: python, django, model

Is is possible to set a default filter in Django models?

Something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
        filtering = [active=True]
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'll have to override the [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyModelManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

*`get_queryset` was `get_query_set` before Django 1.6*

Comment: get_query_set is actually get_queryset

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, as then it's not a "default" filter that can be overridden, but actually a permanent sub-set for objects.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this.  In order to handle the question from the comment above (BjornW), what if you created a second manager called MyInactiveManager with .filter(active=False) and in the model, added inactive_objects=MyInactiveManager().  Would it be possible to then use MyModel.inactive_objects.all() to retrieve all inactive objects?

Comment: Tried it - but where it says in MyModelManager "active=True" it gives me a "not defined" error for my field ...

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by adding managers to the model.  I also created an abstract base class to make it easier to add this to other models without having to replicate the same code - here is the modified example:

```
class MyActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)

class MyInactiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().filter(active=False)

class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyActiveManager()
    objects_inactive = MyInactiveManager()
    objects_all = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

class MyModel(AbstractModel):
    # Define active-enabled model here
```

Now, any model I want to have an "active" (and "timestamp" in this example) field can just inherit from the base model.  When I use MyModel.objects.all() - I get all objects with active=True - this is especially useful if I already have alot of code using the objects manager.  If I want only inactive results, I use MyModel.objects_inactive.all(), and if I want all records regardless of the value of active, I use MyModel.objects_all.all()