# Django model filter with default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I wanna do something similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14925152/10922372), but I want a filter with default value if it's not passed as parameter.

E.G:

```
class MyUserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, is_active=True):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=is_active)


class User(AbstractUser):
    # ...
    manager = MyUserManager()
```

So I don't have to remember to filter with `is_active=True` every time since I will want only active users all the time, **except** when I intentionally pass `is_active=False`.

I don't think `get_queryset()` override works for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you throw in an `if` in there?

```
class MyUserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, is_active):
        if is_active == True or is_active == None:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=is_active)
        elif is_active == False:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=is_active)
```

Comment: Setting is_active=True as method argument already sets its value to True if it's not passed as parameter

Comment: When I encounter a similar problem I just make a separate functions. In your case it might be something like `def get_active_users: return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)` and `def get_inactive_users: return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=False)`. I usually do it when queries get messy with filters and stuff, but it might work in your case as well

Answer (score -1):

Similar to answer 1

```
class MyUserManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self, is_active):

    if is_active not False:
      is_active = True:
    return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=is_active)
```